# Play MOH instead of ringtone in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, ringtone

I'm trying to play Music file ( MOH ) instead of ringing sound.

It's my extention_custom.conf

```
[from-internal]
exten = _X.,1,Verbose(call from: ${CALLERID(num)} to ${EXTEN})
same = n,Dial(Local/${CALLERID(num)}@somewhere,100,g|m(tt))
```

and i defined MOH class in the musiconhold_custom.conf:

```
[tt]
mode=files
directory=/var/lib/asterisk/moh/tt/
sort=alpha
```

sometimes it works and i can hear music instead of ringtone, but sometimes it's silent.

sip_custom.conf

```
[*****]
type=friend
secret=***
context=from-internal
username=****
host=***.***.***.***
allow=all
directmedia=yes
nat=yes
```

i don't know it's useful or not but when i checked the pCap files, everything in both situation were same, but when i could hear music, there is an additional line, it's :

```
SSRC changed from 0xC8F2189B/6305 to 0x1BEA4D36/8
```

Comment: This one is completely debug question. Offtopic on SO

Comment: i dont know how can explain my problem better :( . it's not clear ? im looking for a way to force change SSRC from asterisk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `directmedia` to `no`. SSRC changing likely indicates that RTP media is being handed off from asterisk to the endpoint. If you disallow directmedia, then asterisk will stay in the middle (between the endpoints), and can always play moh.

Keep in mind this may have topology implications for your network, but assuming your endpoints are all on the same LAN with asterisk, and your asterisk server can handle the RTP traffic, you won't see much change.

Comment: actually i added default ringtone before IVR and it works. but your idea is good too. thank you

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it worked out. If you have time, consider updating your question and showing the solution at the bottom. It will likely help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

i Solved this problem by adding raw ringtone at the first of my code

```
[from-internal]
exten = _X.,1,Verbose(call from: ${CALLERID(num)} to ${EXTEN})
same = n,Dial(Local/${CALLERID(num)}@somewhere,100,g|m(tt))
same = n,Ringing()
same = n,Wait(3)
```